# Selenium Web Driver - Unable switch to frame (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

***Here is picture*** ---
[Beginning Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKmHG.png) ---
[Page After Click on a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfEzQ.png)
--I'm a beginner then I have a problem when I using

> GetDriver().switchTo().frame(element) or ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(element)

Here is the HTML:

```
<head id="ctl00_Head1">
<body>
<div id="divPleaseWait" style="display: none"/>
<div>
<a>
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
<div id="TB_overlay" class="TB_overlayBG"/>
<div id="TB_window" style="margin-left: -440px; width: 880px; margin-top: -295px; display: block;">
<div id="TB_title">
<iframe id="TB_iframeContent" frameborder="0" style="width:879px;height:562px;" onload="tb_showIframe()" name="TB_iframeContent303" src="CompanyDetail.aspx?" hspace="0"/>
</div>
```

And my code is

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(GetDriver(), time_out);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.Id("TB_iframeContent")));
```

or

```
GetDriver().switchTo().frame(By.Id("TB_iframeContent"));
```

but I unable switch to that iframe and located the id in that iframe
This is my error out

> Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for frame to be available:
>   [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS
>   (fd412e93-d76e-4934-9fa5-a771c836ffe3)] -> id: TB_iframeContent] Build
>   info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30
>   17:37:03' System info: host: 'ABCV-VN-01-PC', ip: '192.168.3.30',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_51' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.1, platform=WINDOWS,
>   nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   fd412e93-d76e-4934-9fa5-a771c836ffe3 Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_adminMenuCompany"}

Could you please help me?!? I really mad for it!!!!

> Thank you all for supporting. I find that my firefox driver is error with this issue. When I try with chrome driver, It's OK. I think I should update to selenium 3.0

Comment: You have this div which is hidden which seems to contain the iframe you are looking for - <div style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">... Is the iframe visible on the browser when your webdriver code is trying to find it. Is their some other action which is making the div visible?

Comment: Are you sure iframe id is not dynamically changing??

Comment: Your locator is missing quotes... it should be `By.Id("TB_iframeContent")`.

Comment: @Grasshopper Hi, the iframe is visible after click on a button. But, webdriver seem to be NOT find it. I find that webdriver still stay in page at beginning contains html <body>
<div id="divPleaseWait" style="display: none"/>
<div>
<a>
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">  Then I click button it show the html I send on top. Could you share your point?!? You can take a look at picture I update.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur thanks, but It absolutely NOT changing ID

Comment: @JeffC Sorry that I miss that quote on my question :)

Comment: Try once as `GetDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); GetDriver().switchTo().frame("TB_iframeContent");` and let me know

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I try it before then it doesn't work, I have try with css or xpath and it not work too. As the result, I try System.out.println(GetDriver().findElement(By.id("TB_window")).getTagName()) then it sysout "div". It's very hard to me to understand why driver doesn't find tagName "iframe". You could take a look at picture I update on top. Could you have an idea for it? T_T

Comment: It prints div because you're locating div element, are you sure there is only one iframe, may be its in nested iframe, verify it..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I do with JeffC suggest then it only return `<iframe hspace="0" src="CompanyDetail.aspx?" id="TB_iframeContent" name="TB_iframeContent964" onload="tb_showIframe()" 'style="width:879px;height:562px;" frameborder="0"> </iframe>`

Comment: Please do me a favour. Open firepath, inspect the element you want to locate, and then take a screenshot of the page and upload here or [upload in imgur](http://imgur.com/) and add the link in the question/comment. That will help in sorting out, if the element is actually in an iFrame or not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe the `IFRAME` you are looking for is nested inside another `IFRAME`? Run this code and see if the `IFRAME` you are looking for is present in the list.

```
driver.findElement(locator).click(); // click the button to make the IFRAME visible
// you may need a wait here
List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
for (WebElement iframe : iframes)
{
    System.out.println(iframe.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
}
```

---

EDIT:

Have you tried using a frame index? Try the below.

```
driver.findElement(locator).click(); // click the button to make the IFRAME visible
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(0));
```

I would suggest that if the above doesn't work, I would put a breakpoint on the line after you click the button that exposes the IFRAME and inspect the page. Something weird is going on. I don't suppose you can post a link to the page?

Comment: Hi JeffC, It's only return '<iframe hspace="0" src="CompanyDetail.aspx?" id="TB_iframeContent" name="TB_iframeContent964" onload="tb_showIframe()" style="width:879px;height:562px;" frameborder="0"> </iframe>' then how I switch to that iframe. I try 'GetDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); GetDriver().switchTo().frame(Control(By.Id("TB_iframeContent")));' but it's NOT work

Comment: @YuGo What is `Control(..)` here?? And why are not trying as `GetDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); GetDriver().switchTo().frame("TB_iframeContent");`?? Because it takes id and name directly no need to provide by object for this. Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Sorry that I forgot edit my comment. `GetDriver().switchTo().defaultContent(); GetDriver().switchTo().frame("TB_iframeContent");` return `Current window is closed` I do my best. But It's really big trouble for me!

Comment: `<iframe hspace="0" src="CompanyDetail.aspx?" id="TB_iframeContent" name="TB_iframeContent964" onload="tb_showIframe()" style="width:879px;height:562px;" frameborder="0"> </iframe>` Name has  dynamically changing but ID is NOT.

Comment: @Yugo it this iframe element opens in new window??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur No. You can take a look in picture I update on top question. I don't know how to display picture. sorry

Comment: I updated my answer... see if those two suggestions help.

Comment: @JeffC Poor me!!! My firefox driver is error. I try it with chrome driver then it's OK. Maybe I should update to selenium 3.0. I'm using 2.53.1

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the current version of Firefox you will need to update to 3.0.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. If it (or any answer) is helpful, please upvote it.